# Jasmine - Replacing variable in function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, jasmine

I need to test a function when an inside variable equals different things

say

```
Function() {
  var test = "to be changed"
  return stuffHapennedToTestVariable

}
```

I need to change the test variable value to multiple strings to test the returned result.

Comment: if they are pre-defined strings, can't you use an array and a static counter to increment through the array each time it's called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't it the way the function works in your example. There is the pattern of [IOC or dependency injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). The idea is to inject the dependencies of an object/function instead of creating a new instance in the object/function. So in your case, having a variable and set it to a string is the same thing as creating a new instance. So the only way to test it with different strings is to pass in the strings into the function:

```
function functionTotest(test) {
  return stuffHapennedToTestVariable
}

var result = functionTotest( "to be changed")
expect(result).toBe("expected result")
```